# Ajax success/error not called but POST is working

Tags: javascript, node.js, ajax, express, pug

So, may be duplicate, but read some answers, not help...
Node.js project, MongoDB, Jade templates

Ajax in Jade

```
script.
        $('#add_cmt_btn').click(function (e) {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: '/comments/add',
                data: $("#add_cmt_form").serialize(),
                success: function () {
                    console.log('success');
                    $('#comment-text').val('');
                    $("#comments-block").load(location.href + " #comments-block>*", "");
                },
                error: function (err) {
                    console.log('error: ' + err);
                }
            });
        })
```

And form

```
form(method='POST', id='add_cmt_form')
      div.row
          div.col-sm-6
              div.form-group-sm
                  label Add comment:
                  textarea.form-control(name='text', cols='50', rows='3')#comment-text
                  input(type='hidden', name='data_id', value=data.id)
                  input(type='hidden', name='data_type', value=data.type)
                  a.btn.btn-sm.btn-dark(id='add_cmt_btn', style='width:20%') Add
```

In Node (Express route) there is function, that add's comment

```
router.post('/add', auth.ensureAuthenticated, function (req, res) {
    req.checkBody('text', 'Text is required').notEmpty();
    let errors = req.validationErrors();

    if (errors) {
        return console.log(errors);
    } else {
        let comment = new Comment();
        comment.author = req.user.login;
        comment.text = req.body.text;
        comment.type = req.body.data_type;
        comment.data_id = req.body.data_id;

        comment.save(function (err) {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err)
            }
        });
    }
});
```

When i click on "Add" button comment added to DB, but page isn't refresh, need to update with F5 to view last comment.
But I don't see any log in console (no error, no success), val of textarea not nulled and div isn't resfreshed.
What I do wrong in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not ending the request. You're missing [res.send()](http://expressjs.com/es/4x/api.html#res.send); in your express route.

```
router.post('/add', auth.ensureAuthenticated, function (req, res) {
    req.checkBody('text', 'Text is required').notEmpty();
    let errors = req.validationErrors();

    if (errors) {
        console.log(errors);

        return res.status(500).send('Something bad happened!');

    } else {
        let comment = new Comment();
        comment.author = req.user.login;
        comment.text = req.body.text;
        comment.type = req.body.data_type;
        comment.data_id = req.body.data_id;

        comment.save(function (err) {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
                return res.status(500).send(err.message)
            }

            res.send('saved');
        });
    }
});
```